# run an .exe file onload in VB.NET codebehind

Tags: vb.net, exe, behind

i have song data (title and artist) that display on a web page.  I would like to display this info on a twitter account and have found this great twitter .exe file that will tweet what ever i want to the twitter account.  How do i simply run an .exe file from the code behind page to execute this twt.exe file?

Comment: Look at [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method:

```
Process.Start("c:\somepath\twt.exe")
```

and if you wanted to pass arguments:

```
Process.Start("c:\somepath\twt.exe", "arg1 arg2 arg3 ...")
```

Or even better, take a look at the [`Twitter OAuth developer page`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) and directly use their public API.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the API.  Much better (IMO) to use an API to interact with a service/app than a third party executable.

Comment: Process.Start gives me an error in VB.NET 3.5 (Visual Studio)  how do I use Process.Start ?

Comment: What error do you get? Did import the `System.Diagnostics` namespace in which this class is defined?

Comment: yeah, i just did that.  it is not giving an error now, but makes the load time very long....and doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: Well, I guess there's some problem with the executable then. Also don't forget that an ASP.NET application might run in IIS under an account which doesn't have many permissions. So if this executable is attempting to create files or write to some places where this account doesn't have permission it might fail.